# html Button is not rendered correctly on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I have an html button which renders correctly on all browsers, but it is not rendered properly on iOS devices.

Here is css

```
.textCont .block button {
    border: none;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    height: 23px;
    width: 35px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
}
```

In iOS devices it shows button wider then it is supposed to be it is widened towards left. I thought it can be because of the margin-left I have, but after setting it to 0px nothing changed. I feel lost, any idea what can be the issue ?

Comment: Are you using media query to target iDevice?

Comment: @SajithNair yes I am using media queries

Comment: I believe you are not targeting the iDevice properly. You have to use the correct media query to target each version of iDevice based on resolution/retina factors. Once you target properly, then only the corresponding css takes effect

Comment: @SajithNair Is there a way to identify if I am targeting the right way ? And even if that's the case why everything else works totally fine ? I just need to understand where to look.

Comment: You can change the background color etc and see if thats getteing reflected in the device.

Comment: @SajithNair everything works as expected, all controls are adjusted as expected the only problem is that one particular button is widened and only on iOS devices.

Comment: Since you are targeting with media query, why don't you adjust the width: 35px; property for this particular device and reduce it to say 30px; or less

Comment: That would be a problem since I have an image inside button ... and since a button is always shifted/widened towards left it looks ugly and not centered.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot

Comment: You can also try `margin-left: -5px; padding-left: 0px;`

Comment: I have added an image.

Comment: Try `background-position: 40% 50%;` Also check here for various other options here https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/background-position/

Comment: That was padding man. I have set  padding: 0px; and everything works fine. I guess it is yet another css magic thanks a lot @SajithNair

Comment: OK I will add as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions which can lead to answer.

Try `margin-left: -5px; padding-left: 0px;`

Try `background-position: 40% 50%;` (more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/background-position/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the element inherits padding from somewhere. Please try resetting padding by adding "padding: 0;"

Tip: When in doubt, always check how the browser computes CSS properties by using web inspector and switch to computer tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` to your CSS

Comment: Tried it, same result